# Why is aconitase classified as a lyase?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, nomenclature

Aconitase in the TCA (*tricarboxylic acid*) cycle isomerizes citric acid to isocitric acid via cis-aconitic acid intermediate. Since overall it functions as an isomerase, why it does not belong to isomerases? Why does it belongs to lyases even though it involves hydrolysis of water in second step? Should not it belong to hydrolases in this way?

So how it can be justified that it is lyase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [mechanism of aconitase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aconitase#Mechanism) classifies it as a lyase, even if (under most physiological conditions), the relative concentrations of substrates results in it catalysing the conversion of citrate to isocitrate. In short, it is not an isomerase because the substrate is **released after each step**.

[image]

As the mechanism of aconitase shows, it catalyses the conversion of either citrate or isocitrate to aconitate as well as the reverse reaction. This is similar to the reaction catalysed by [fumarase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fumarase), which is the reversible addition or removal of water.

[image]

Because the physiological concentrations of citrate is much larger than the concentration of isocitrate, aconitate overall catalyses the reaction from citrate to isocitrate, and does so via catalysing **two** lyase reactions.

Regarding the other part of your question, [hydrolases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolase) are a completely different group of enzymes, and none of the reactions involved are related to hydrolases in any way.

While water is in fact involved in the reaction, it is not used in the process of hydrolysis. To be specific, [hydrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolysis) (in its enzymatic/organic, and not chemical sense) requires that water be a substrate required to break apart a molecule A-B into A and B. Since the addition of water does not result in citrate/isocitrate being broken down into two smaller organic molecules, aconitase is not a hydrolase.

Comment: @JM97 Updated answer to clarify what is and what is not a hydrolase.